# Cannot checkout/merge files that have been ignored

Tags: git

We **have had** this line in the `.gitignore`: `plugins/third-party/`. But the extension was buggy and we needed to add it to the repo later in the process. So we removed that line added everything and pushed it within the `dev` branch.

Right now I am on a feature branch and doing a `$ git pull origin dev` or `$ git merge origin dev` just doesn't checkout the newly added files. Checking out the dev branch shows that they are there and in the repo.

I guess that is because the files have been ignored in the past, but what can I do to come around that?

Comment: Well was this feature branch created _before_ you made the changes to `.gitignore`?

Comment: YES, that's the case…

Comment: If you really added the files then I don't see how they could not be there in the `dev` branch.  As for other branches, merge operations, etc., this might be another story.

Comment: To make that clear: The files are in the dev branch, but I cannot pull/merge them in the feature branch.

Comment: After the merge, what does `.gitignore` look like?  Does it reflect your having re-added the files?

Comment: Yes. The line in question is not in the `.gitignore` anymore.

Comment: I am confused. Applying #3 (last resort) of @Kokogino answer resulted in an Error. `git update-index --refresh  --no-assume-unchanged --verbose` did not create any output, but now the directory appears. ?? Why ??

Comment: Appears ... in what? `git status` output? `--no-assume-unchanged` clears the bit that tells `git status` to assume that the file is unchanged, so `git status` would no longer make that assumption, and would actually *look at* the file. That could be why. (You would have had to have *set* the bit earlier. Once set, it *remains* set until you clear it.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you can try:

1. Make sure that not only the `third-party` folder is pushed, but also the `.gitignore`.
2. Instead of using `pull` or `merge` try to use `rebase`: `git rebase dev`
3. If you can find the hash of the commit that added the `third-party` folder, then `cherry-pick` this specific commit: `git cherry-pick c20299d09e9` (replace `c20299d09e9` with your hash)

I hope one of those options work for you.

Comment: The first option is a good suggestion; not sure if 2 or 3 would do much.